# Do ad-blockers work on PWAs?

Tags: google-chrome, ios, adblock

It seems there is quite a push for PWAs lately, chrome 72 on android just added support for TWA and it seems iOS 12.2 will also add more support.

I find it really cool this recent shift to web techonologies, but something that bothers be is online tracking, with native apps there is nothing you can about it.

But I was wondering if PWA are just contained web apps (meaning they run on the browser) and now we have mobile ad blockers, is tracking code/request blocked within them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I accidentaly discovered the answer to my questions, I installed the PWA version of instagram along the native version, and will browsing the feed I noticed I see no ads on the PWA version.

[image]
[image]

So I guess that settles my question, at least until something changes on further versions of iOS.